# vgs collect form field validation for card exp date

Tags: javascript

i'm looking to see if the `validCardExpirationDate`, which doesn't exist in vgs collect's `field()` documentation, can be customized *and* display the proper error message.

so far, under the `create` doc section, under 'field validation' i see:

> You can set up multiple validation rules based on your needs and requirements. Use errorMessages key in the form state to track down validation error messages for each field.

there is one example section under the `custom validation` tab that allows regexes, and under the 'card validation' tab, there is an example validation string, `validCardExpirationDate`, which we're using.

https://www.verygoodsecurity.com/docs/vgs-collect/js/integration/

and under the `field()` docs > `parameters` > `validations`,
`validCardExpirationDate` isn't a documented option, though it is an example given.

https://www.verygoodsecurity.com/docs/api/collect/#api-formfield

---

problem:
i need the card exp validation to only allow for `mm/yy` format, but it so far allows `mm/yyyy` as well.

i've already added `validCardExpirationDate` which is only given as an example in the code sandbox on the doc site, but not actually documented. it works, but isn't restrictive enough.

when i tried adding a custom regex and tested it with a `mm/yyyy` input, the built-in error message was "the value doesn't match a pattern", which isn't the correct error message either.

wondering if there is a way to validate with vgs collect that prevents the `mm/yyyy` from displaying and only allows the `mm/yy` format that shows the correct error message as well.

thanks!